# Any way to add my C# project as a reference in IronPython / IronRuby?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ironpython, ironruby

I know how to reference an existing .dll to IronPython, but is there any way to add my project as a reference like I can between Visual Studio projects?

Or is it best practice to create a separate class library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add reference to a project since it's a Visual Studio thing.

I suggest that during the development process, call `import` (IronPython) or `require` (IronRuby) with the full path of your project assembly like c:\dev\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.dll.

Comment: Your IronRuby bias is showing :). In IronPython you can't `import` by path; you need to `clr.AddReference` first and then `import` the class.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. Was looking for an easier way to get IronRuby to know my classes. I think this is something you have to plan for from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do that using SharpDevelop.
Kinda like this:

http://i42.tinypic.com/hwb8z9.gif